# Joomla: export csv

Tags: csv, joomla, chronoforms

I need to export two csv files (both are a sub set of a table)from joomla and push them into an FTP folder. Is there a way to do this with Joomla itself? I.e. within the admin chronoforms. Or should I be creating a script / query to run off the DB?

Comment: com_banners will download a csv file, you could take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV Export [GH] action is included in ChronoForms v4 if that's what you are using. You can find it under "Data Export".